# Lists of lists of lists

Tags: haskell

What is a good way to represent the type `LoL a`, being a list of lists
of ... of `a`?  The nesting level is arbitrary, but uniform over all
elements of the outer list.

The case I have in mind is to apply a grouping on the members of a
list, and then to apply a next grouping on each subgroup, and so on. It
is not known up front how many groupings one will have to apply. Hence:

```
rGroupBy :: [(a -> a -> Bool)] -> [a] -> [...[a]...]
```

Extra brownie points for the type signature of `rGroupBy` ;-)

Example:

Suppose `deweyGroup i` groups the elements based on the i-th number

```
rGroupBy [deweyGroup 1, deweyGroup 2] 
         ["1.1", "1.2.1", "1.2.2", "2.1", "2.2", "3"]
```

gives:

```
[ [ [ "1.1" ], [ "1.2.1", "1.2.2" ] ],
  [ [ "2.1" ], [ "2.2" ] ],
  [ [ "3" ] ]
]
```

**Postscript**

One day later, we have 4 excellent and complementary solutions. I'm very pleased with the answers; thank you all.

Comment: interesting question. When you say "it is not known up front" do you mean at compile time? If so then you may be out of luck, as haskell is statically typed.

Comment: in C/C++ a list is usually an array, an array is usually a 2 dimension matrix, make a list of arrays means that you are increasing the dimensions by 1, from 2 to 3, a list of array is a 3D matrix ( from an abstract point of view ); i don't know Haskell but probably your problem is just about matrix/vector dimensions.

Comment: @user827992, in Haskell, a list is a list, not an array. (It's a singly-linked list, to be precise)

Comment: @dflemstr i was just making an example about how i would approach this in C/C++ and i suggest that probably the solution lies in a multi-dimensional approach.

Comment: @jberryman: indeed I mean at compile time. Secretly I hope that some haskell wizard conjures some nice type from his GADT hat, both solving my problem and providing an example to learn from. I think this is possible with GADTs (as this seems to allow vectors with fixed length enforced by the type system), but I find them currently out of my grasp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following example should be close to what you had in mind. First we declare type-level natural numbers. Then we define vectors, which carry their length as a phantom type (see [Fixed-length vectors in Haskell, Part 1: Using GADTs](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2005-May/015815.html)). And then we define a structure for nested lists of lists of ... which carries the depth as a phantom type. Finally we can define correctly typed `rGroupBy`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}

import Data.List (groupBy)

data Zero
data Succ n

data Vec n a where
    Nil  ::                 Vec Zero a
    Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (Succ n) a

data LList n a where
    Singleton :: a           -> LList Zero a
    SuccList  :: [LList n a] -> LList (Succ n) a

-- Not very efficient, but enough for this example.
instance Show a => Show (LList n a) where
    showsPrec _ (Singleton x)   = shows x
    showsPrec _ (SuccList lls)  = shows lls

rGroupBy :: Vec n (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> LList (Succ n) a
rGroupBy Nil
    = SuccList . map Singleton
rGroupBy (Cons f fs)
    = SuccList . map (rGroupBy fs) . groupBy f

-- TEST ------------------------------------------------------------

main = do
    let input = ["1.1", "1.2.1", "1.2.2", "2.1", "2.2", "3"]

    -- don't split anything
    print $ rGroupBy Nil input
    -- split on 2 levels
    print $ rGroupBy (Cons (deweyGroup 1) 
                           (Cons (deweyGroup 2) Nil))
               input 
  where
    deweyGroup :: Int -> String -> String -> Bool
    deweyGroup i a b = a!!idx == b!!idx where idx = 2*(i-1)
```

Answer (score 13):

Another way to enforce the constraint that all branches have equal depth is to use a nested datatype:

```
data LoL a = One [a] | Many (LoL [a])

mapLoL :: ([a] -> [b]) -> LoL a -> LoL b
mapLoL f (One xs) = One (f xs)
mapLoL f (Many l) = Many $ mapLoL (map f) l

rGroupBy :: [a -> a -> Bool] -> [a] -> LoL a
rGroupBy [] xs = One xs
rGroupBy (f:fs) xs = Many $ mapLoL (groupBy f) $ rGroupBy fs xs
```

Expanding the definition of `LoL`, we see that informally,

```
LoL a = [a] | [[a]] | [[[a]]] | ...
```

Then we can say, for example:

```
ghci> rGroupBy [(==) `on` fst, (==) `on` (fst . snd)] [ (i,(j,k)) | i<-[1..3], j<-[1..3], k<-[1..3]]
```

to get back

```
Many (Many (One [[[(1,(1,1)),(1,(1,2)),(1,(1,3))]],[[(1,(2,1)),(1,(2,2)),(1,(2,3)), ...
```

Comment: Also very nice. It took me a while before I realized that groupBy f has type [a] -> [[a]], and that each successive application of map adds an extra nesting level (e.g. map . map . groupBy f :: [[[a]]] -> [[[[a]]]]).

Answer (score 10):

What you actually have is a tree.  Try representing it with a recursive data structure:

```
data LoL a = SoL [a] | MoL [LoL a] deriving (Eq, Show)

rGroupBy :: [(a -> a -> Bool)] -> [a] -> LoL a
rGroupBy (f:fs) = MoL . map (rGroupBy fs) . groupBy f
rGroupBy []     = SoL

deweyGroup :: Int -> String -> String -> Bool
deweyGroup i a b = a!!idx == b!!idx where idx = 2*(i-1)
```

`rGroupBy [deweyGroup 1, deweyGroup 2] ["1.1", "1.2.1", "1.2.2", "2.1", "2.2", "3.0"]` gives:

```
MoL [MoL [SoL ["1.1"],
          SoL ["1.2.1","1.2.2"]],
     MoL [SoL ["2.1"],
          SoL ["2.2"]],
     MoL [SoL ["3.0"]]
    ]
```

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Also, take a look at Rose Trees. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.0.0

Comment: Very nice solution. The only problem I see is that a tree structure doesn't force uniform depth.

Comment: @Petr Would it be possible to modify [this](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/statically-checked-perfect-binary-trees/) to force uniform depth?

Comment: very nice indeed. And I had missed the point that it's actually a tree. Thanks.

Comment: @JeffreyBurka: a couple of the other answers do so

Answer (score 7):

If you want to enforce uniform depth, there is a (fairly) standard trick to do that involving polymorphic recursion. What we'll do is have a spine of "deeper" constructors telling how deeply nested the list is, then a final "here" constructor with the deeply-nested list:

```
data GroupList a = Deeper (GroupList [a]) | Here a deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
```

Actually, the type as defined has one aesthetic choice that you may wish to vary in your code: the `Here` constructor takes a single `a` and not a list of `a`s. The consequences of this choice are sort of scattered through the rest of this answer.

Here's an example of a value of this type exhibiting lists-of-lists; it has two `Deeper` constructors corresponding to the depth-two nesting that it has:

```
> :t Deeper (Deeper (Here [[1,2,3], []]))
Num a => GroupList a
```

Here's see a few sample functions.

```
instance Functor GroupList where
    fmap f (Here   a ) = Here   (f a)
    fmap f (Deeper as) = Deeper (fmap (fmap f) as)
    -- the inner fmap is at []-type

-- this type signature is not optional
flatten :: GroupList [a] -> GroupList a
flatten (Here   a ) = Deeper (Here a)
flatten (Deeper as) = Deeper (flatten as)

singleGrouping :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> GroupList [a] -> GroupList [a]
singleGrouping f = flatten . fmap (groupBy f)

rGroupBy :: [a -> a -> Bool] -> [a] -> GroupList [a]
rGroupBy fs xs = foldr singleGrouping (Here xs) fs
```

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the aesthetic aspect: I believe the solution of Phil Freeman took the other choice. I find his code easier to understand, though your explanation of the "spine of constructors" initially helped a lot there as well. In fact, the comments in your code hint at important non-obvious details, such as that `flatten` flattens the inner type, but adds a `Deeper` constructor (I was wondering why it wasn't called "deepen"); and that you use nested `fmap`s to traverse both GroupLists and normal lists. Subtle!

Answer (score 1):

As a type-hackery exercise it is possible to implement this with standard lists.

All we need is an arbitrary depth groupStringsBy function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts,
  UndecidableInstances, IncoherentInstances,
  TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.List
import Data.Function

class StringGroupable a b where
    groupStringBy :: Pred -> a -> b

instance (StringGroupable a b, r ~ [b]) => StringGroupable [a] r where
    groupStringBy f = map (groupStringBy f)

instance (r ~ [[String]]) => StringGroupable [String] r where
    groupStringBy p = groupBy p
```

Which works like this:

```
*Main> let lst = ["11","11","22","1","2"]
*Main> groupStringBy ((==) `on` length) lst
[["11","11","22"],["1","2"]]
*Main> groupStringBy (==) . groupStringBy ((==) `on` length) $ lst
[[["11","11"],["22"]],[["1"],["2"]]]
```

So we can use this function directly (although it has to be put in reverse order):

```
inp = ["1.1", "1.2.1", "1.2.2", "2.1", "2.2", "3"]

deweyGroup :: Int -> String -> String -> Bool
deweyGroup i a b = a!!idx == b!!idx where idx = 2*(i-1)

-- gives: [[["1.1"],["1.2.1","1.2.2"]],[["2.1"],["2.2"]],[["3"]]]
test1 = groupStringBy (deweyGroup 2) . groupStringBy (deweyGroup 1) $ inp
```

But if you want to use your original sample, we can hack it too.
First we need a variable argument function which pipelines all the arguments but the last one in reverse order via `.` and then applies the resulting function to the last argument:

```
class App a b c r where
    app :: (a -> b) -> c -> r

instance (b ~ c, App a d n r1, r ~ (n -> r1)) => App a b (c -> d) r where
    app c f = \n -> app (f . c) n

instance (a ~ c, r ~ b) => App a b c r where
    app c a = c a
```

Works like this:

```
*Main> app not not not True
False
*Main> app (+3) (*2) 2
10
```

Then expand it with a custom rule for our predicate type `type Pred = String -> String -> Bool`:

```
type Pred = String -> String -> Bool

instance (StringGroupable b c, App a c n r1, r ~ (n -> r1)) => App a b Pred r where
    app c p = app ((groupStringBy p :: b -> c) . c)
```

And finally wrap it in `rGroupBy` (supplying `id` function to be the first in the pipeline):

```
rGroupBy :: (App [String] [String] Pred r) => Pred -> r
rGroupBy p = app (id :: [String] -> [String]) p
```

Now it should work for any number of grouping predicates of type `Pred` producing the list of the depth equal to the number of supplied predicates:

```
-- gives: [["1.1","1.2.1","1.2.2"],["2.1","2.2"],["3"]]
test2 = rGroupBy (deweyGroup 1) inp

-- gives: [[["1.1"],["1.2.1","1.2.2"]],[["2.1"],["2.2"]],[["3"]]]
test3 = rGroupBy (deweyGroup 1) (deweyGroup 2) inp

-- gives: [[[["1.1"]],[["1.2.1","1.2.2"]]],[[["2.1"]],[["2.2"]]],[[["3"]]]]
test4 = rGroupBy (deweyGroup 1) (deweyGroup 2) (deweyGroup 1) inp
```

So it is possible (and probably can be simplified) but as always with this sort of hackery is not recommended to be used for anything but the exercise.